# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined at app.js:4

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Sorry if this is simple but I'm new and I don't really get what is this about.
I'm trying to add li's to ul when a tag called btn is pressed and I get this error.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const list = document.querySelector('.list'); 
document.btn.addEventListener('click',onClick);
function onClick(e){
console.log('clicked');
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New item'));
list.appendChild(li);
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.btn.addEventListener('click',onClick);` should be

`btn.addEventListener('click',onClick);`

Comment: Thank you it was so simple.